# Was ist dieser Satz für ein Satztyp?

Tags: relative-clause

> Welche positiven und welche negativen Begleiterscheinungen lassen sich bei den Olympischen Spielen, ***der wichtigsten internationalen  Sportveranstaltung***, absehen.

Zuerst dachte ich, dass er ein Nebensatz ist, aber das kann nicht sein, denn es gibt kein Verb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es ist eine **Apposition**, auf Deutsch **Einfügung**.

Eine Einfügung ist kein vollständiger Satz, weil, wie du bemerkt hast, kein Verb vorhanden ist. Sie dient der Präzisierung oder Ergänzung des zuvor Gesagten. Appositionen werden links und rechts durch Kommata getrennt.

Andere Beispiele:

> Meine Schwester, Anne, geht mit mir gerne spazieren.
>
> Das höchste Gebäude der Stadt, die Kirche, wird demnächst saniert.
>
> Der Hund, ein Labrador, wohnt bei uns schon seit drei Jahren.

Comment: Dein erstes Beispiel geht ebenso ohne die beiden Kommata. Es würde dann aber etwas anders gelesen werden.

Comment: @CarstenS richtig, das wäre dann aber keine Apposition mehr, sondern ein zusammenhängendes "Meine Schwester Anne".

Comment: Genau. Aber dem Fragesteller ist vielleicht nicht klar, dass das auch möglich ist.

Comment: In dem Fall, danke für die Ergänzung ;)